# No downtime deployment with multiple varnish backends

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

We have a set of varnish servers with multiple backends, and we want to achieve no downtime deployment when we updating backend codes.

We did a little research, and here is what we do:

```
varnishadm backend.set_health backend1 sick
upgrade(backend1)
varnishadm backend.set_health backend1 auto

varnishadm backend.set_health backend2 sick
.......
```

For some reason, this still gives us 503 errors during deployment. 
Can someone advice if this is the right approach? if it is wrong, what should we do?

Many thanks!

Comment: I guess the requests that are in progress will receive 503. From where are the 503 issued? From the backend or from varnish?